# Is there a common method for implementing a "batch table" in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I'm writing some forum software. Let's additionally say that that forum software has a personal messaging component. I'd like the user to be able to check a few messages out of that list, and then click a delete button somewhere else to delete all of those messages.

Another similar application is GMail, or pretty much every other kind of webmail application.

Is there a common pattern for implementing this? I can just stick a database row ID in each table row, but that seems like a kludge....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, sticking a database-friendly identifier in every row *is* the standard solution to this problem. In your case, the identifier would be in the `value` attribute of the checkbox.

The extended pattern is to let every single operation accept a list of identifiers instead of only one (so that all your operations can act as batches).

Comment: +1 for suggesting the way to generalize this.

Answer (score 2):

The usuabl way of acconplishing this is to let the BROWSER send all selected IDs with an array.. similar to this:

```
<input name="test[]" value="123" /> foo<br />
<input name="test[]" value="133" /> bar<br />
<input name="test[]" value="3" /> barfoo<br />
<input name="test[]" value="4" /> foobar<br />

<?php
if (!empty($_GET['test']) && is_array($_GET['test'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['test'] as $k => $v) {
        echo '<br />delete id' . (int) $v;
    }
}
?>
```

Please note that I did not run this code. So there might be a typo in it. :D

Comment: +1 -- I was not aware of this -- I was defining separate `name` s for each and looping through `$_POST`!